# Retrieving Permission Description Returns 'null'

Tags: java, android

In order to get the description of a permission. I used the following code:

```
    PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    PermissionInfo pinfo = null;
    try {
        pinfo = packageManager.getPermissionInfo("android.permission.BODY_SENSORS", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        if(pinfo != null) Log.i("permissions","pInfo not null???????????????????????????????????????");
        Log.i("permissions ",  pinfo.loadDescription(packageManager)  + " *** "  + pinfo.group);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
```

But for some permissions, like- `android.permission.BATTERY_STATS`, I have a `null` `char` sequence when I call `pinfo.loadDescription(packageManager)`. I don't understand why? And I'm trying to find the reason, but no way to get it. Any android expert could please explain it for me?

Answer (score 4):

> I have a null CharSequence when I call pinfo.loadDescription(packageManager).I don't understand why?

Because Google elected not to provide a description (or a title) for that permission. This is true for many of the `signature`-level permissions. You can examine [the AOSP edition of the framework manifest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml) to get a sense of what you can expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I figured out the reason why :)